# Capturar peticiones http del sistema con python

Tags: python, http

Necesito saber como hacer para detectar con python cuando el sistema o alguna aplicacion esta tratando de acceder a internet. Necesito saber cuando se esta intentando generar trafico hacia/desde internet.
la pc accede a internet a traves de un portal en el que se inicia una sesion, la idea es hacer un servicio con python que haga todo automatico. Por ejemplo:
 Se va a realizar una busqueda en internet con el navegador, el servicio detecta la peticion e inicia una sesion en el portal cautivo, cuando se carga la busqueda se cierra la sesion; y asi con cualquier peticion que se haga desde el navegador o cualquier otra aplicacion.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, aquí estaremos encantados de resolver dudas puntuales, problemas que te impidan seguir con tu proyecto, etc. Pero las dudas generales difícilmente son contestadas.

Comment: Gracias de antemano, mi duda consiste en saber si existe alguna forma de detectar con python todas las peticiones que hace el sistema hacia internet.